# Second div is showing first - float:right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a div that floats to right and two child DIVs that also float to right. The issue is that the Second Div always shows up first. I have tried adding clearfix to the parent div which did not work at all. Is there a way to fix this without adding width to the child divs?

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="div1">
        Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Div 2
    </div>
</div>

.parent-div {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline;
}

.parent-div>* {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: `.parent-div>* {
    float: left;
}` ?

Comment: Multiple Float rights will have the objects display in a right to left order.  div1 will be the rightmost, div2 will be the leftmost in this case.  I might use a flex instead of float right, especially if the parent is already floating right.  You could do display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif both of your solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="div1">
        Div 1
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Div 2
    </div>
</div>

.parent-div {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: inline;
}

.parent-div>* {
    float: right;
}
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
```

- have you added the clearfix at the correct position, this will make the `div2` not to respect to the `div1 float`.